# Why is binarySearch giving me the wrong index?

Tags: java, binary-search

I sort an array of points (using a custom Point class) by natural order, and I save a reference to a point. Then I sort it again using a comparator, and I use binarySearch to find that same point (being sure to specify the current order). This is done in the context of a loop, and binarySearch gives me an incorrect index every other iteration. Why?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Point[] pts = new Point[6];

        pts[0] = new Point(19000, 10000);
        pts[1] = new Point(18000, 10000);
        pts[2] = new Point(32000, 10000);
        pts[3] = new Point(21000, 10000);
        pts[4] = new Point(1234, 5678);
        pts[5] = new Point(14000, 10000);

        Arrays.sort(pts);
        for (int i = 0; i < pts.length-2; i++) {

            Point firstP = pts[i];    

            // Get a point from the array
            Point secondP = pts[i+1];
            System.out.println("The point I saved: " + secondP.toString());

            // Find that same point and return it
            // Why is this sometimes a different point?
            Arrays.sort(pts, firstP.SLOPE_ORDER);
            int secondI = Arrays.binarySearch(pts, secondP, firstP.SLOPE_ORDER);
            System.out.println("The found point: " + pts[secondI].toString());
            System.out.println("-----");

            Arrays.sort(pts);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output from the first two iterations. Why is it sometimes returning a different point than the one I searched for?

```
The point I saved: (14000, 10000)
The found point: (14000, 10000)
-----
The point I saved: (18000, 10000)
The found point: (19000, 10000)
-----
```

Heres's thee custom Point class, if that helps.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

    // compare points by slope
    public final Comparator<Point> SLOPE_ORDER = new BySlope();

    private final int x;    // x coordinate
    private final int y;    // y coordinate

    // create the point (x, y)
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // slope between invoking point and end point
    public double slopeTo(Point end) {
        if (end == null)
            throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Point object is null");
        if (this.equals(end)) 
            return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        if (end.x - this.x == 0) 
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        return (double) (end.y - this.y) / (double) (end.x - this.x);
    }

    // is invoking point lexicographically smaller than second one?
    // comparing y-coordinates and breaking ties by x-coordinates
    public int compareTo(Point second) {
        if (this.y < second.y)
            return -1;
        if (this.y == second.y && this.x < second.x)
            return -1;
        if (this.y > second.y)
            return 1;
        if (this.y == second.y && this.x > second.x)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    // return string representation of this point
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }

    private class BySlope implements Comparator<Point> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Point q1, Point q2) {
            if (q1 == null || q2 ==  null) 
                throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Point object"
                        + "is null");
            if (Point.this.slopeTo(q1) < Point.this.slopeTo(q2)) 
                return -1;
            if (Point.this.slopeTo(q1) > Point.this.slopeTo(q2))
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 - But didn't I ensure that they are ordered correctly with Arrays.sort(pts, firstP.SLOPE_ORDER)?

Comment: what hits me in your code is you are using `Point` comparator to  obtain `secondP` and do obtain `pts[secondI]` you are using `BySlope` comparator.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish  with the two different comparison types - can you give an example of what result you expected?

Comment: @wrschneider99 - Sure, in this example code, I expected the point that I found to be the same point that I saved. I'm using two comparison types because, in the actual program, I want to make sure points with the same slope (with respect to a reference point) are grouped together, and I want to make sure points grouped together are sorted by Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's strip this down a bit. Apparently, the first `Arrays.sort` invocation is unrelated to the problem: `binarySearch` fails, and this is only invoked *after* the array has been sorted wrt. "slope order".

So apparently, the problem is with your `Comparator`. There is nothing wrong with the `Comparator` as such, as it looks like it fulfills the contract established in the `Comparator` [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). However, it is not consistent with `equals`: there might be points `a`, `b`, for which `compare(a, b) == 0`, but `a.equals(b) == false`. However, as binary search only "sees" the order established by your comparator, it cannot distinguish between `a` and `b`, so it might return the first element that "looks like" either of them.

Your problem is that you *define* these points `a` and `b` as equivalent through your comparator, but nonetheless *expect* binary search to distinguish between them and return a point that is not only equivalent, but *equal* to the one you supplied. Try outputting `firstP.slopeTo(secondPt)` and `firstP.slopeTo(pts[secondI])` - are those values equal?

Finally, a solution is to break ties in your ordering by defaulting to the natural order of Points. That is, replace the `return 0;` in `BySlope.compare` with `return q1.compareTo(q2)`.